# using modal with default laravel 5 registration

Tags: php, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I try to use default laravel 5 registration/auth with modal instead of views
but it didn't work the user is not inserted in the database.
here is the code

```
<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">×</span>
  <form class="modal-content animate"  action="/SurveyApp/public/accueil">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="container">
    <h2>Registration</h2>
    <label><b>Name</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" required>
      <label><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required> 
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
      <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

      <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

my redirect route would be accueil

```
Route::post('/accueil', 'Auth\RegisterController@create');
```

can you tell me please what's the problem ?
thanks for your help.

Comment: Set `method=POST` in your form element.

Comment: Change this line and set method="post"  for this

 action="/SurveyApp/public/accueil"   to

 action="/accueil"

Comment: after adding method=POST , I have this error              Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create() must be of the type array, none given